# Any example on binding Silverlight Combobox with both text and image from database

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am working with Northwind and using WCF RIA (with EF 4.0) to pull data on to Silverlight client.  All I am trying to accomplish is to have ComboBox showing list of Categories with both CategoryName and Picture from database.  I am using ValueConverter to convert bytes to bitmapimage, but getting Catastrophic error.

Anyone has any ComboBox example which binds to Categories/Employees table of Northwind (along with pictures) using WCF RIA.

thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: exactly the same error as here http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/181807/411359.aspx#411359